# Facebook Page update through external page

Tags: facebook

I'm new to Facebook App development and I got this Problem:
I've created a Facebook Page (so I'm the administrator). Now I would like to have an external Webpage with a simple textarea and a "send" button. So everybody who has the link to this page could update this Facebook Page even without a Facebook account. This status update should be send by my page administrator account.
I thought I could write an app and authorize this app to publish_streams on the page and after the authorization I could switch $fbuser = $facebook->getUser(); to $fbuser = IDOFMYACCOUNT.
So the fbuser would be always my account wich is allowed to post to the Page.
If I try to use this application with an other browser (wich isn't logged in to my fb account) I get this error: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

So this is the way I thought I could solve my problem.
Do you guys have an idea how I (and other people who don't have a FB account or don't wan't to login or I don't want to add them to Facebook Page administrator) could update the Facebook Status of a Page from an external website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need your token "baked in" to your code and some sort of admin back end to update the access token before it expires.

Also you need `manage_pages` permission and the token of the page if you want to post as the page.

This can be accessed from `/me/accounts`

Comment: Could you or someone else give an example how to get this particular token wich I would need (page? user?) and how to "bake" it in and post something with this token? I got the manage_pages permission inside the scope.

Comment: @Knob1 you just need a way to hold the token in the back end. Either permanently in the code or saved in a database. To get the particular token you need to access `/me/accounts` and find the page under that response. Example https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts